# RStudio and python virtual environment - Python specified does not exist

Tags: python, bash, rstudio, virtualenv, reticulate

I'm aiming to run python from RStudio. My setup is Windows RStudio Version 1.2.1335 and conda 4.7.12 from GitBash.

The RStudio support document (https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360022909454-Best-Practices-for-Using-Python-with-RStudio-Connect) suggests creating a virtual environment in EVERY project.

Create virtual environment.

```
bash$ virtualenv .venv --python=python3.6
```

This creates a .venv directory in .

But then how to activate .venv? Running:

```
bash$ source activate .venv
```

Can't find .venv.

Running:

```
bash$ conda activate ./.venv
bash: [: too many arguments
bash: [: too many arguments
bash: [: too many arguments
bash: [: too many arguments
bash: [: too many arguments
bash: [: too many arguments
(c:\<project-dir>\.venv)
```

So the conda virtual env is running - not sure about the 'too many arguments' messages.

Then to RStudio.

Setting the in .Rprofile to ".venv/python". The .venv directory doesn't contain .venv/bin/python, instead the python.exe is at .venv/python.

`Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = ".venv/python")`

Restart R.

```
print("hello")
```

> Error in py_discover_config(required_module, use_environment) : 
>   Python specified in RETICULATE_PYTHON (.venv/python) does not exist

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Create virtual environment.

```
bash$ virtualenv .venv
```

This creates a .venv directory in .

Activate .venv.

```
bash$ source .venv/Scripts/activate
```

Then to RStudio.

Setting the in .Rprofile to ".venv/python". The .venv directory doesn't contain .venv/bin/python, instead the python.exe is at .venv/python.

```
library(reticulate)
Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = here::here(".venv/Scripts/python.exe"))
```